# Generic Collection of T for ICollection of DbEntities

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, collections, generic-collections

The Situation-

Have EF database entities with collections of other database entities as navigation properties all of which are not exposed outside of the project. Each of these entities are nested in base classes that allow public read and protected set access to the Db entity's property values and are the classes the business layer will work with. So these base classes also need collections of their Db entity's navigation properties.

What I have now-

I am still working on how I want the data layer to interact with with the other layers that reference it. So I have been experimenting with creating collection classes that can be set equal to a collection of Db entities and create a collection of the base class that the Db entity is nested in. The collection is then exposed outside the class though an interface as well as the base class. The interface gives access to some custom methods of collection class like accepting DTOs and prebuilt quires but would hide any Add methods.

The Problem-

I would like to create a generic base class for the collections but cant seem to find a way. I have gotten close to something workable but it was ugly and confusing. Below is an outline of what I'm working with. The narrowing operators in the entity class work well. I would rather have widening operators and narrowing operators in the base class so I could keep the New method private for the base classes but I don't want to expose the actual database entities outside the Data Layer.

Interops Namespace referenced by all projects in solution-

```
Public Interface IGenericEntity
End Interface

Public Interface INavigationPropertyEntity : Inherits IGenericEntity
End Interface

Public Interface IDbEntityToExposedEntityCollection(Of TEntity As IGenericEntity)
  'Used to hide Add method
End Interface

Public Interface IPublicEntity
  ReadOnly Property NavProps As IDbEntityToExposedEntityCollection(Of INavigationPropertyEntity)
End Interface
```

Data Layer project-

-Database Entities

```
Friend Class DbEntity1
  Public Shared Narrowing Operator CType(ByVal value As DbEntity1) As NavigationPropertyEntity
    Return New NavigationPropertyEntity(value)
  End Operator
End Class

Friend Class DbEntity2
  Public Sub New()
    NavigationPropertyDbEntities = New HashSet(Of DbEntity1)
  End Sub

  Public Property NavigationPropertyDbEntities As ICollection(Of DbEntity1)

  Public Shared Narrowing Operator CType(ByVal value As DbEntity2) As PublicEntity
    Return New PublicEntity(value)
  End Operator

End Class
```

-Exposed Base Classes

```
Public Class NavigationPropertyEntity : Implements INavigationPropertyEntity
  Private _value As DbEntity1

  Friend Sub New(value As DbEntity1)
    _value = value
  End Sub

End Class

Public Class PublicEntity : Implements IPublicEntity

  Dim _value As DbEntity2
  Friend _NavProps As DbEntityToPublicEntityCollection(Of INavigationPropertyEntity, DbEntity1, NavigationPropertyEntity)
  Public ReadOnly Property NavProps As IDbEntityToExposedEntityCollection(Of INavigationPropertyEntity) Implements IPublicEntity.NavProps
    Get
      Return _NavProps
    End Get
  End Property

  Friend Sub New(value As DbEntity2)
    _value = value
    _NavProps = new DbEntityToPublicEntityCollection(Of INavigationPropertyEntity, DbEntity1, NavigationPropertyEntity)(_value.NavigationPropertyDbEntities)
  End Sub

End Class
```

-Entity Specific Collection

```
Friend Class DbEntityToPublicEntityCollection(Of IEnt As INavigationPropertyEntity, DbEnt As DbEntity1, ExpEnt As NavigationPropertyEntity)
  Inherits HashSet(Of IEnt)
  Implements IDbEntityToExposedEntityCollection(Of IEnt)

  Public Sub New(value As HashSet(Of DbEnt))
    For Each ent In value
      Dim exp As NavigationPropertyEntity = ent
      Dim i As INavigationPropertyEntity = exp
      MyBase.Add(i)
    Next

  End Sub


End Class
```

***Additional Info Edit***

The main issue is being able to have a generic collection declared something like,

```
Friend Class DbEntityToPublicEntityCollection(Of IEnt, DbEnt as class, ExpEnt As class)
```

because in the New sub ExpEnt cannot be converted to DbEnt and a TryCast will just result in a runtime error.

Like I said, I tried setting up classes that are inherited by the exposed and entity classes so a new method with a parameter for the exposed class could be set up but with trying to have the interfaces in there it got unmanageable pretty quick. Then again I have not worked much with making my own generic types before so I'm not sure if this is even a proper strategy.

Comment: Why make it so complex? Don't wrap: map!

Comment: I guess I thought that's kind of what I was doing with the Exposed Base Classes? Unless I am misunderstanding that how the Data Mapper pattern works that is.